# Get timestamp from time string with today/tomorrow's date

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, timestamp

Need some help with converting a time string to a timestamp. Say my time is `07:00:00`, how do I make this into a timestamp but also after the current date time?

Currently I have `datetime.strptime('07:00:00', '%H:%M:%S')` but that returns `1900-01-01 07:00:00`.

Comment: Please accept the best answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 1):

Well, something like this should work:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

today = dt.today()
time = dt.strptime('07:00:00', '%H:%M:%S')

time = time.replace(day=today.day, month=today.month, year=today.year)

print(time) # datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 20, 7, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check [this page](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/timestamp-datetime).

```
from datetime import datetime
# current date and time
now = datetime.now()
timestamp = datetime.timestamp(now)
print("timestamp =", timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing `today`s parts:

```py
from datetime import datetime
today = datetime.today()
mytime = '07:00:00'

then = today.replace(**dict(zip(['hour', 'minute','second'], map(int, mytime.split(':')))))
print(then)
```

output:

```
2019-07-20 07:00:00.108203
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import datetime as dt_lib
from dateutil import parser as date_parser

def get_upcoming_7_o_clock_timestamp():
    today = dt_lib.datetime.now()
    upcoming_7_o_clock = date_parser.parse(today.date().isoformat() + ' ' + '07:00:00')


    if today > upcoming_7_o_clock:
        upcoming_7_o_clock = date_parser.parse((today + dt_lib.timedelta(days=1)).date().isoformat() + ' ' + '07:00:00')
    return upcoming_7_o_clock
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
from datetime import datetime, date
#first get current date
current_date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d');
timestamp = int(datetime.timestamp(datetime.strptime(current_date + ' 07:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
```

Output-

> 1563586200

Answer (score 0):

You can add today's date to your time and then apply `strptime`.

```
from datetime import date, datetime


my_datetime = f"07:00:00 {date.today()}"
print(datetime.strptime(my_datetime, "%H:%M:%S %Y-%m-%d"))
# 2019-07-20 07:00:00
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be the easiest way that avoids stupid double conversion of the date to the string and back:

```
import datetime

date = datetime.datetime.now()
time = datetime.datetime.strptime( '07:00:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()

datetime.datetime.combine( date, time )
```

gives:

```
datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 20, 7, 0)
```

(probably using `date` and `time` as variable names was not the best idea, but for the sake of clarity... =)

Comment: Please don't encourage poor code quality using (very) bad variable names.